# Where to obtain Appendix B of STS Historic American Engineering Record TX-116?

Tags: space-shuttle, history

At the close of the Shuttle program the National Park Service and the Smithsonian (maybe others as well) embarked on a project to document the Space Transportation System as part of their Historic American Engineering Records.

It appears to have been a comprehensive and worthy effort. The resulting document *HAER TX-116* can be found in a series of oddly fragmented and overlapping files on the NASA websites by searching "HAER TX-116 pdf".  From what I can tell there is no one .pdf of the entire document.

My goal is to create one such pdf and upload it to archive.org

I've managed to assemble what appears to be the entire document in 13 separate files, except for "Appendix B".  The Appendices are selections of black-and-white photographs.  The existing ones are

- A - SSP Historic Photos
- C - SSME Historic Photos
- D - ET Historic Photos
- E - SRB Historic Photos

Another oddity of the document is that there is no table of contents so I do not know for sure what Appendix B contains. I assume it is Orbiter Historic Photos. It comprises pages 437-585 of the document.

Does anyone know where to obtain Appendix B of HAER TX-116?

Comment: Interesting.  Sounds like the equivalent of the *Apollo Program Summary Report* for the shuttle program.  It would be useful to post the links on meta once you have a complete set.

Comment: @DrSheldon agreed! I'll add to the 'useful resources' page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I stumbled across the whole document - including the appendix I was missing -posted on this NASA website "[Space Shuttle Recordation](https://www.nasa.gov/agency/crm/shuttle/narrative.html)".

Although many of the drawings appear to have been extracted from the [Shuttle Crew Operations Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf), there is still some useful new information.