# Reference request: Rocketdyne Document R-3896-4 "F-1 Rocket Engine Illustrated Parts Breakdown"

Tags: apollo-program, history, engine-design, reference-request

Various sections of the Rocketdyne F-1 document R-3896 can be found scattered about the web, but I can't find R-3896-4.  It's described as

> R-3896-4 F-1 Rocket Engine Illustrated Parts Breakdown

> This manual contains illustrative
> and columnar listings of all parts
> of the engine that can be disassembled, reassembled, repaired, replaced, or overhauled. This
> manual locates and identifies the
> interrelationship of parts, aids
> in the requisition of replacement
> parts, and indicates part usage and
> inter changeability and recommended
> repair or replacement for the F-1
> engine and its individual components
> and parts.

I am looking for a .pdf of this document.

[image]

Screenshot from R-3896-1 INTRODUCTION page xii

Comment: Simply googling "r-3896-4" brings you this:

https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/10699045/marshall-space-flight-center-f-1-engine-static-test-

You have to register at Yumpu and I did not want to do that (they don't accept 10MinuteMail email adresses), so I can't say if that matches your document.

Comment: @JanDoggen The title of that is listed as "F-1 Engine Static Fire Test", so I doubt it is the right document. I bet it just references that document number.

Comment: @JanDoggen That's a HAER document, much newer vintage than what I'm looking for. Thanks for the attempt!  A similar HAER document is discussed here: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38449/6944 I did actually try a google search before posting the question.

Comment: After an extremely thorough effort at doing fuzzy searches of various archives, I'm fairly confident no publicly accessible PDF is available. Someone's going to have to be generous and share one with you (alleged physical copies of this document are for sale on Ebay). I wish you luck!

Comment: Please supply a reference as to where the doc name  "R-3896-4 F-1 Rocket Engine Illustrated Parts Breakdown" was seen by you.  In some of the old NASA archives there are part breakdowns for the F1 but none with that exact title.  If the ref for that title is given, perhaps i could get further. After some more looking i willl summarize what I have found.   I think you need to request a copy of a doc from nasa.  They are not online; only the refs.  Probably a copying and shipping fee and a lengthy wait is needed.  I'll fill in more when I get further.

Comment: @tckosvic I edited in a screen shot from the document R-3896-1 *INTRODUCTION* which lists all the other sections of the document by number and title. It is the exact text that I quoted in the question. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have recently acquired a copy of R-3896-4 from the Ebay seller called2Voyage mentioned. If you are still interrested, just add a comment below mine and tell me where I should send it to and I'll be happy to oblige.

Comment: @Darkcoucou Congratulations! If you want to perform a public service, scan it and post it to the internet archive or some other generally available place. Future researchers besides myself will thank you!

Comment: @OrganicMarble The seller provided me with a digital copies, making it easier to upload. I'm currently acquiring the other F-1 Manuals as well as the J-2 Manuals from the same seller and will upload them to the WebArchive in bulk as soon as I have recieved all of them. I'm very glad if I could help a fellow rocket historian with that. :)

Comment: @Darkcoucou that's wonderful! When you've completed the process, consider posting an answer here with the links.

Comment: @OrganicMarble here you go: https://archive.org/details/rocketdyne-f-1-manuals & https://archive.org/details/rocketdyne-j-2-manuals

Comment: That's 7400+ pages for you

Comment: @Darkcoucou you are my hero! Many thanks.

Comment: @Darkcoucou wow, that "illustrated parts breakdown" is all I dreamed it would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else interrested, I have provided Rocketdyne Document R-3896-4 "F-1 Rocket Engine Illustrated Parts Breakdown" among all the other F-1 Rocket Engine Manuals here:

[archive.org/details/rocketdyne-f-1-manuals](https://archive.org/details/rocketdyne-f-1-manuals)

I have also provided the respective J-2 Manuals which can be found here:

[archive.org/details/rocketdyne-j-2-manuals](https://archive.org/details/rocketdyne-j-2-manuals)

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for sharing this with us!

Comment: @called2voyage You're welcome!