# What was the exhaust pressure of the Saturn V?

Tags: rockets, engine-design, saturn-v, rocket-equation

I am trying to write some code to simulate rocket launches, and I am doing a proof of concept using the Apollo 11 as a model, to fill my values. When calculating thrust I am using the equation:

F=m⋅Ve+(Pe−P0)Ae ,

where F
is force/thrust, m
is mass and Ve
is velocity.

I have found m
dot and Ve
but can't find any values for Pe - Exhaust pressure
or Ae - Exit area
.

EDIT - I AM LOOKING FOR THE F1 ENGINE

Comment: The Saturn exhaust pressure was different at each stage since there were multiple different engines. Are you looking for the exhaust pressure of the F1, J2, AJ10-137 or something else?

Comment: Duplicate of  [Whats the exit pressure of the F-1 engine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/61259/whats-the-exit-pressure-of-the-f-1-engine)