Combustion gas of gas generator right through nozzle?
I was reading page (13) of the book "Rocket, Owner's Workshop Manual" and I came across this diagram: 
Does the gas generator exhaust gas go directly to the combustion chamber in the engine as shown in the diagram?

I'm asking whether the exhaust of the gas generator is usually connected like that

The text "Main combustion chamber" in the image is after the throat inside the nozzle. I think there should be a line pointing to the part above the throat which is the real combustion chamber. Then it becomes clear that the exhause from the gas generator goes into the nozzle and not the combustion chamber.

The placement of the text "Main combustion chamber" is wrong. The chamber is the very small thing between the injector plate and the throat. The nozzle is the big part between throat and the injection of the exhaust gas. The nozzle extension is the very big part below this injector at the bottom of the diagram.

In the schematic you show, the hot exhaust gas from the gas generator passes through the turbines of the turbopumps and then is injected into the engine nozzle partway down, to aid in cooling the nozzle extension.
This has been done in the real world in some engines, notably the F-1 used in the Saturn V first stage and the J-2 used in Saturn upper stages.

The now relatively cool gas generator exhaust
gas is directed into the lower section of the
thrust chamber to provide film cooling of the
double-wall portion of the nozzle.

This schematic shows how the gas generator exhaust was injected into the nozzle (highlighting mine).

Source: F-1 ENGINE FAMILIARIZATION
TRAINING MANUAL
Many gas generator engines simply dump the turbine exhaust overboard, however. Sometimes it passes through a nozzle to provide a little thrust, sometimes this nozzle is gimbaled to provide roll control authority.

Image source: Cycles for Earth to Orbit Propulsion
See also:

Atlas Rocket Burning Hose
What is an "exhausterator" and what does it do?
Saturn I's four outer engines' gas generator exhaust, why not vent to the side like the four inner engines?
Where is the gas generator on the RS-68?


Excellent drawing! I did not know before this part of the nozzle was built with shingles. Did they weld or braze all those shingles? Must have been several hundred meters of seams for a single F-1 engine, if not several kilometers.

I did not find any info about how the nozzle was built. I found this sentence about the shingles:"Film cooling of the inner walls
is achieved by injecting turbine exhaust gas,
supplied to the cavity between the walls by the
turbine exhaust manifold, into the thrust chamber
exhaust stream through injector slots formed by
23 rows of overlapping shingles that form the
inner wall." The repair manual does talk about welding them.

@Uwe these documents were all provided in this great answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/59780/6944

In this diagram https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_F-1#/media/File:SaturnF1EngineDiagram.png the text "thrust chamber" seems to be wrong, it is the nozzle. The combustion chamber is not visible, it is hidden behind many other parts.

@Uwe In those Rocketdyne documents they call the "thrust chamber" the combustion chamber and the first part of the nozzle down to where the nozzle extension connects. I don't see it used that much in that way elsewhere, but the Rocketdyne documents are pretty consistent.
